# System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Retrivieng the COM class factory for component with CLSID 80080005

Tags: windows-server-2012

I am using a a third party tool named SurferMap9 . I am trying to call it from my web application but its not working and below error is produced. The detailed error is

**

> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Retrivieng the COM class
>   factory for component with CLSID {B2933480...} failed due to following
>   error : 80080005 Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT :
>   0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE))

**

I am trying this on Windows server 2012 r2. I have tried all solutions relating to DCOM (Component Services) setting found on Google, but still its not working. 
I am guessing this is Server 2012 error, as this Configuration correctly works on Windows server 2003.

Please help me.

Comment: You are looking at the error from the wrong end.  You need to find out why this program is failing to start.  Look for things like a log file, an entry in the Application event log, the vendor's support channels.

Comment: Yes you are right, actually I have installed program but had not registered it with Serial key, after registering its working fine....thanx.